# From Json String to XContentBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a file in json format, is there a way to convert it to a XContentBuilder?

What I want to do is to read a file with some mapping and then convert it to XContentBuilder

Something like:

```
XContentBuilder builder = JsonXContent.contentBuilder().source(String json);
```

Answer (score 14):

Usually the API should accept a `String` or `byte[]` so you shouldn't need to convert. Maybe you want `CreateIndexRequestBuilder#addMapping(String, String)`?

If you really, really, really want an `XContentBuilder` you can make an `XContentParser` and copy the contents to a builder. As of Elasticsearch 5.2 this should do it:

```
    String message = "{\"test\":\"test\"}";
    XContentBuilder b = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().prettyPrint();
    try (XContentParser p = XContentFactory.xContent(XContentType.JSON).createParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, message)) {
        b.copyCurrentStructure(p);
    }
    System.err.println(b.string());
```

You could probably also do *something* with raw but I don't think that is worth it.

Pre 5.2 you don't need the `NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY,` part.

Comment: solution working for me  (ElasticSearch 6.8)  ^_^

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work for me:

```
import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.jsonBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentParser;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType;

...

String message = "{\"bob\": \"test\"}";
XContentParser parser = XContentFactory.xContent(XContentType.JSON).createParser(message.getBytes();
parser.close();
XContentBuilder builder = jsonBuilder().copyCurrentStructure(parser);
```

Comment: This worked in Jackson 2.7.5 but in 2.9.8 it throws "JsonGenerationException: No current event to copy" because of the early close(). Use the code snippet from Nick with the try.

Answer (score -1):

```
val x: XContentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().value("{\"bla\":\"blub\"}")
```

Not sure if this answers your question because you don't provide much information but you can also use strings to add a mapping to an IndexRequestBuilder:

```
new CreateIndexRequestBuilder(adminclient)
  .addMapping("typeName", "{\"mapping\" : \"mapping\"}")
```

If you really want and need to create a XContentBuilder Object from a string you can do so like this:

```
String mapping = "{\"bla\":\"blub\"}"
XContentBuilder x = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().value(mapping)
```

Comment: the XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().value(mapping) does not work as expected since I get a no object root. I suspect that still we need to add a .startObject()?